# Creating a swipe left and right(using the mouse) web based application

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web

I want to create a web application using jquery/angular where I am going to use the mouse to swipe left and right between stored pictures(pretty much like tinder). For the swiping part I am thinking of using jquery's on drag and drop. Can I get advice on how I can approach this?

thank you

Comment: For UX, you may also want to consider allowing for left and right arrow key controls as well?